# Does closing an app also kill its background thread?

Tags: apps, background-tasks

Does closing an app also end any background threads in Windows Phone 8.1 or 8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope**, *this is not under your control*

For example, killing WhatsApp doesn't stop you receiving notifications. It can mean part of the app is still running in the background.

Comment: Notifications are NOT a guaranteed sign that an app is using a background process. A push-notification can happen without an app implementing a background process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Closing an app does NOT kill the background process it may have. To kill a background task in Windows Phone 7.x and 8.0 you can access the [background process options in settings](http://www.wpcentral.com/conserve-windows-phone-battery-life-managing-background-apps). In Windows Phone 8.1 you can disable a background process in the battery saver application.